# JavaScript fire second click

Tags: javascript

i have a question about listening the second click, 
so i have here 2 Divs and 1 input, and by every click
each element change the background color of every element.

i want to fire second click, so if i click two times on same element, 
than it shuld display an alert.

JavaScript:

```
var divTag = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

for (var i = 0; i < divTag.length; i++) {
    if (divTag[i].tagName == "DIV" || divTag[i].tagName == "div") {
         if (divTag[i].addEventListener) {
            divTag[i].addEventListener('click', callback,false);
         } 
         else if (divTag[i].attachEvent) {
            divTag[i].attachEvent('on' + 'click',callback);
         }
    }
}

function callback(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    target.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

HTML :

```
<div id="old">
    <input style="margin: 10px;" type="textbox" />
    <div id="new"></div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#old {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:yellow;
}
#new{
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    background-color:lightblue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v6d6veyv/

Can you help me? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: By initializing a variable and check on every click that it has been previously clicked or not.
Check this out [JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/v6d6veyv/5/)

Answer (score 1):

using a variable `numberOfClicks` and incrementing it everytime the div is clicked works as well.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/m9160vcu/)** here

Answer (score 0):

If you mean double click, you can use `dblclick` instead of `click`:

```
divTag[i].addEventListener('dblclick', callback,false);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answerm, but i  don't want to click one after the other, so i clicked an element, than for an example i waited a while, than i clicked again.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using the `ondblclick` event. May be a little easier. Attach with `element.addEventListener("dblclick", /* whatever here */ )`

Answer (score 0):

Could you add an attribute to the targeted selector ie data-count="0" and then when you click on the element listen for this and then perhaps increment the value to 1 so that next time you click you can check to see if the value is 0 or 1 and then do whatever you need to do based on that?

Hope that makes sense/helps,
Lew

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the best way.. but you could implement a counter..

```
var counter = 0;
if (counter %2 === 0) {//do stuff}
```

I did it here to yours...

http://jsfiddle.net/n516avaf/

You would probably want to change it up a bit though, but hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect whether the click is again on the same element, then you can modify your function in the following way:

```
var target = ''; // Make this variable global.

function callback(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    if ((target == e.target) || (target == e.srcElement)) { //Check whether the event's target is same as the previous.
        alert('hello');
    } else target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if (prevDiv) {
        prevDiv.style.backgroundColor = "";
    }
    target.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    prevDiv = target;
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/v6d6veyv/1/

if you want the doubleclick, then just listen for `dblclick` event

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to fire an alert when the div clicked is the same.. so this should do the work:

```
if(prevDiv === target)
        alert('same div');
```

result:

```
function callback(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var target = e.target || e.srcElement;
    if(prevDiv === target)
        alert('same div');
    if(prevDiv) {
        prevDiv.style.backgroundColor = "";        
    }
    target.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    prevDiv = target;
    e.stopPropagation();
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6d6veyv/2/)

Answer (score 0):

How about something simple like...

**HTML:**

```
<span class="clickable">Click me!</span>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.clickable').on('click', function() {
    if(this.clicked){
        alert('oh hai!');
        return;
    }

    this.clicked = true;

    $(this).text('Click me again!');
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1ny7o6o9/

Answer (score 0):

By initializing a variable and check on every click that it has been previously clicked or not.
Check this out 
[`JSFiddle Link`](http://jsfiddle.net/v6d6veyv/5/)